# Philips BDM4350UC is locked

Tags: display

My Philips monitor BDM4350UC is showing the message "display controls locked". I have looked in the following manual to see how to unlock it, I have a joystick control at the back.

https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/b/bdm4350uc_00/bdm4350uc_00_dfu_eng.pdf

I have tried with no luck

- pressing joystick for 10-30 seconds
- turning montor off and pressing joystick for 10-30 seconds
- waiting for message and then pressing joystick for 10-30 seconds

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

[image: philips message]

**Answer from @harrymc got me here**, clicking reset sorted my issue

[image]

Comment: See the methods [listed here](https://tv-sound-monitors.philips.com/s/article/How-to-lock-or-unlock-the-Philips-monitor-s-OSD-menu-1692010989670?language=en_US).

Comment: Thanks also came across that aritcle and tried the arrow down thing. Not quite sure what to do now

Comment: There is some software available [here](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/BDM4350UC_27/brilliance-4k-ultra-hd-lcd-display/support). Try the "SmartControl Software" and the "Drivers Windows 10", hoping that one of them will help.

Comment: Cool add an answer and I can accept and vote up, cheers bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some software available in the
[BDM4350UC/27 Support page](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/BDM4350UC_27/brilliance-4k-ultra-hd-lcd-display/support).

Try the "SmartControl Software" and the "Drivers Windows 10",
hoping that one of them will help.